# Remove all hidden elements in html using pyquery in python

Tags: jquery, python, html, pyquery

I have a piece of html code where I have to remove the hidden elements from it. I tried the following code

```
from pyquery import PyQuery

html_data = '''
<div style="display: none;">This is a hidden div.</div>
<p>This is another paragraph.</p>
<span style="display: none;">This is a span</span>
<div>This is a div.</div>
'''

pq = PyQuery(html_data)
pq(':hidden').remove()
pq.html()
pq.remove(':hidden')
pq.html()
```

This is not removing the hidden elements. Any idea how to remove those hidden elements

Answer (score 2):

Since the pyquery doesn't support the pseudo classes like :hidden, I have added my own custom class ('myhide') to use that as a selector. So I have used the following code to remove the hidden elements

```
from pyquery import PyQuery

html_data = '''
<div style="display: none;" class="myhide">This is a hidden div.</div>
<p>This is another paragraph.</p>
<span style="display: none;" class="myhide">This is a span</span>
<div>This is a div.</div>
'''

pq = PyQuery(html_data)
pq('.myhide').remove()
pq.html()
```

So the output comes like this

```
This is another paragraph
This is a div
```